# Custom post type Admin Page

Tags: custom-post-types, images, wp-admin

I've got a custom post type that is going to be showcasing images that users have submitted, at the moment, check the images that users have uploaded is a boring task – I have to go into each post, check the featured image, then publish.

[image: Standard page]

Ideally, I'd love to be able to show this custom post type like this in the admin:

[image]

in wish I pull through the featured image and can publish or delete it there and then. Rather than the former way of handling it.

Is there way of customising custom post type pages? I'm yet to find any solutions to this. Any links or code is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

1.
The easiest way is to use the plugin "Admin Columns", to show the picture in columns https://wordpress.org/plugins/codepress-admin-columns/

2.
You also can code your own admin page with the function add_submenu_page().
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page
You can create a query, loop through the posts and show the pictures.

Comment: The submenu page could be the best route. I don't want the table at all (unless it's impossible to not have it). Do you have a resource for queries on submenu pages?